# Setting up a Rascal example project

Tags: rascal

How do I setup a Rascal-MPL project to consume the DSL built with Rascal?

I don't seem to find any resource that details how to solve that particular problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation hasn't been written for that case but here goes:

- Use `newRascalProject` from `util::Reflective` to create a basic setup. For both the DSL project and the consuming project that makes sense.
- `mvn install` in the DSL project, if you won't have the DSL project folder open in Eclipse or VScode or if you are working bare bones Unix/Maven.
- In RASCAL.MF of the client project add `Require-Libraries: |lib://dsl-project|`
- In pom.xml of the client project add a dependency on the DSL jar.
- Restart the console or terminal for a file of the client project.

In the terminal the active version of the path configuration for the interpreter will be printed. It should have the DSL project in the list of `srcs`.

In VScode log for the Rascal LSP you can see the path configuration printed when compiling/checking source files in the client project. There the DSL project should be in the `libs` path.

If the DSL project isn't compiled to .tpl files that appear in the target folder and eventually in the jar, you will get spurious error messages in the client code. In that case trigger the compiler in the DSL project by saving the top module, or run `mvn install` again. Revisit the pom file for the settings of the `rascal-maven-plugin`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I need some clarity: 
Are you saying I need to create another Eclipse project for the example? 
Basically can you explain the first step to me a bit?
Can you link me to a git/code repository that does something similar, that would facilitate clarity?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe I gave an answer to a different question than you asked :-) What do you mean by "the DSL" concretely? Is this an example in our docs or something you downloaded or something else?

Comment: In Eclipse you can always use the "New Project Wizard" and that gives you a clean project to work with. Then you can create a new file with "new File Wizard" and import the module from the demo library like so: `import demo::lang::Pico::Syntax;` for example.

Answer (score 0):

For those landing at this page and trying to find an example of calling [newRascalProject](https://www.rascal-mpl.org/docs/Library/util/Reflective/#util-Reflective-newRascalProject) with working parameters...

The first parameter is a 'location'. While it is documented how to use this parameter (https://www.rascal-mpl.org/docs/Rascal/Expressions/Values/Location/), it still took my some time to figure out that a location is not a regular string, and not using double quotes " but |.

So if you try:

```
newRascalProject ("home:///Projects/rascal_playground", "hello2")
```

You get the following error:

```
Advice: |https://www.rascal-mpl.org/docs/Rascal/Errors/CompileTimeErrors/UndeclaredVariable/UndeclaredVariable.html|
```

Including the variable name for the 2nd parameter...

```
 newRascalProject ("home:///Projects/rascal_playground", name="hello")
```

... gives the same error.

This is the correct example:

```
newRascalProject (|home:///Projects/rascal_playground|, name="hello")
```